LaTeX Template for Zeitschrift fur Naturforschung - Section A Journal of Physical Sciences
I am working on a new paper to the journal:
Zeitschrift fur Naturforschung - Section A : Journal of Physical Sciences
The web-site for this journal does not give a LaTeX template.
Is it available in anywhere? We are deeply worried how to start the paper.
Thank you for the great help!
With best wishes,
Sundar

Have you contacted the journal's editorial office for advice?

I sent a mail & I'm waiting for a reply.. It will be easy for authors if the journals provide a template in Word or LaTeX.

The journal's instruction sheets don't appear to provide templates for either Word or LaTeX.

Exactly - That's my problem.

The journal may not be providing specific templates, but it does provide some useful general guidelines. As an author, I would interpret them as follows: Use only well-known packages, use the package defaults as much as possible, use only Latin and Greek letters (that is actually one of the very few specific suggestions they provide), don't engage in visual formatting of any kind, and use BibTeX along with the unsrt bibliography style to create sequentially numbered citation call-outs and the formatted bibliography. That'll simplify life greatly for the journal's editorial staff...

If the publisher does not provide a template, then it is often acceptable to use pretty much any format within reason...so pick one and go nuts! Suggestions include RevTeX (APS, AIP journals), Institute of Physics (iopart.cls), achemso, and the standard article class.

just use article class. The last thing the journal will want is a load of custom macros approximating their layout as most likely they will just accept latex as a convenience to the author but re-key it into their in house production system anyway.

David - Thank you for the kind advice.
